# How to get around max_variables_input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I'm creating a LOOONG form with thousands of different input values (~2900 inputs, to be more exact) being passed through (it's supposed to generate a marketing email based on the values entered in the form, but there are about a dozen possible sections for the email, each with hundreds of customizable attributes that could change the appearance of the email generated).  The problem I'm running into (I think) is that I'm passing the max_variables_input limit of 1,000 for my server and ending up with a bunch of "**Notice: Undefined index:**" errors and broken code on the other end.

Outside of asking our host to raise the input limit, I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to limit the inputs passed through to the action script to those that are being used?

The way I have the form set up, I have the email modules that are being used appearing in divs with IDs:

```
<div id="SectionDiv1"></div>
<div id="SectionDiv2"></div>
<div id="SectionDiv3"></div>
<div id="SectionDiv4"></div>
<div id="SectionDiv5"></div>
<div id="SectionDiv6"></div>
```

(Note: Not all of these divs are necessarily in use...the number of modules is determined by a number input:)

```
<label>Number of Sections</label> <input name="nosections" id="nosections"
class="2-digit-number" type="number" min="1" max="6" value="3">
```

All other modules that aren't being used are hidden from display in another div:

```
<div id="hiddenelements" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Is there a way I can send only the inputs that I'm using into the action script?

Comment: You mean something like `$("div").not(":visible");` ?

Comment: if all 2900 can change values independently, it's going to be impossible for a human being to use. if the values can't always be completely different, use defaults and ship only changed values.

Comment: you can remove the elements `onsumbit` that are not use like `$('ELEMENT').remove()`

Comment: As I said, they're not all being used.  The section choices determine which set of inputs are displayed to be edited and used in HTML generation.  I just don't know how to send only the inputs I'm using.

Comment: Thanks, Minhaz...that's helpful!  I'll see if I can figure that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the `max_input_vars` setting of php, you can set that value in an .htaccess file as well:

```
php_value max_input_vars 3000
```

See the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars).

To answer your question, you can remove the blocks that are hidden using javascript and as you have also tagged the question with jQuery:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  $('#hiddenelements').remove();
});
```

Comment: This is perfect.  Thank you, Jeroen!